# Is [notepad] on-topic?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

I noticed yesterday that there is a [notepad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/notepad) tag with 505 questions. From the tag wiki:

> Notepad is a simple text editor for Microsoft Windows. Use this tag for **issues relating to interfacing with Notepad** and/or **duplicating Notepad functionality**.

Just from the wiki, we can presume there will be many questions along the lines of "How can  I change the font in Windows Notepad?" and "hi i need to write notepad clone in c++ thanx".

For example, here are a few questions:

- [Change the default of encoding in Notepad](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43522510/6850771) *about how to use Notepad, not  programming*
- [Tosca: Can we scan Notepad.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42975077/6850771) *still not about programming*
- [Notepad How to replace different values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41774540/6850771) *Yeah that's still about Notepad usage*

Questions of this sort belong on [Super User](https://superuser.com).

However, many questions with this tag are unrelated to the usage *or* programming of Microsoft Notepad, and instead are about various tools/programs that open Notepad:

- [Notepad keeps printing default page setup through sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42597768/6850771) *SQL opening Notepad*
- [Delete a .txt file after it's closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43371157/6850771) *Powershell opening Notepad*
- [Copying text to a notepad instance in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41641049/6850771) *C# opening Notepad*

And the vast majority of them are 100% unrelated to Microsoft Notepad, and are about user-created text buffers/editors:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/41727016/6850771 *Crappy C# Text Buffer != Notepad*
- [Excel - exporting as TXT with text position](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41446936/6850771) *Excel != Notepad*
- [AS3 / AIR, Generate a .txt file by pressing the save button without dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41563893/6850771) *Really? Android?*

What should we do? I'm thinking something along the lines of retagging/migrating the questions and/or blacklising the tag.

Comment: @Ðаn You use Notepad for programming, yet there is no way to "program" Notepad. Stack Overflow is about ***programming***. I used a paper and pencil to write code ideas while on an airplane because I didn't have my laptop. Does that mean we should have the tag [tag:paper-pencil], and I should ask questions about how to sharpen/erase?

Comment: By that logic we should also get rid of [vi] and [emacs] ([elisp] should be enough for everybody :) )

Comment: @Arkadiy Nope, [tag:vi] and [tag:emacs] are definitely programmable. Vi actually has its own [site](https://vi.stackexchange.com/), so maybe most questions belong there. However, they have their own scripting syntax, recognize RegEx-es, actually accept command line arguments, and are fully functional text editors. Notepad is nothing but a text box with the default Windows save/open/rename tools.

Comment: Like I said, [elisp] should be enough.

Comment: @Arkadiy From the tag wiki, **Emacs Lisp is the extension language for the GNU Emacs text editor, and in fact, most of the functionality of Emacs is implemented using Emacs Lisp.** Editors such as [tag:ed] [tag:nano] [tag:vim] [tag:vi] don't use anything related to Emacs. Can't tell if you're joking or not :P

Comment: Notepad is invariably the first program that Windows programmers attack with their first stab at UI Automation code.  Pretty important, nobody is going to answer a "I can't make it work on xyz" question.

Comment: @HansPassant You make a good point, but are there any actual questions on SO related to Notepad UI automation?

Comment: Did you look at the [notepad] questions?  First one I saw: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42224880/17034

Comment: Note that questions about _software tools commonly used by programmers_ are on topic ([help/on-topic]). One could argue that Notepad is such a tool.

Comment: @DidierL I really hope notepad is not commonly used by many programmers...

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon Yes, me too… But I think a lot of wannabe programmers use it. Well, we might not expect good questions from those anyway… But it is also a last recourse tool for developers, since it is provided with Windows.

Comment: @DidierL one could argue that Windows is a software tool commonly used by programmers, yet that doesn't mean that general Windows questions are on topic.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144273/discussion-on-question-by-md-xf-is-notepad-on-topic).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Questions about how to use notepad.exe as *a programming tool* are on-topic. It happens to be a horrible editor, but we don't ban questions about a certain tool from the site just because the tool is bad. For example we also allow questions about Eclipse.

Meaning that if some poor soul is using notepad.exe as their source code editor, questions about how to use it as such would be on-topic. For example this question would be on-topic:

Q: How do I get source code formatting in notepad.exe?
A: You can't get that.

However, questions about how to "make a notepad" shouldn't use that tag, nor do they really need to. I think the tag wiki is misleading and should be rewritten.

Questions about how to use notepad.exe for other purposes than programming are off-topic.

Questions about how to programmatically do evil things with notepad.exe are on-topic, but I don't think such questions will necessarily benefit from using that tag.

I suspect there might also be questions about [notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/notepad%2b%2b) that are incorrectly tagged as [notepad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/notepad).

Comment: There's a predicate to that "phrase" that most like to ignore "software tools commonly used by programmers; and is **a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development**" The notepad questions described on the question, don't qualify, using any metric, as problems unique to software development. Windows is a tool commonly used in a programing context, yet we do not allow "how to install windows with a predefined set of programs" questions.

Comment: “_For example we also allow questions about Eclipse._” Now wait and look at downvotes to count Eclipse users on meta?

Comment: Popular does not equal bad. Eclipse isn't a bad IDE. Notepad isn't a bad editor. Both have their misgivings, but both serve their intended purpose, regardless of whether that purpose aligns with the goals of the user. Let's keep it objective, no?

Comment: @Braiam - Windows has many usages. I think the percentage of people using Notepad who are trying to write programs is much larger than the percentage of people using Windows who are trying to write programs. Plus 100% of the people who are trying to program in Notepad are doing it on Windows (I can't imagine anyone is actually sophisticated enough to emulate Notepad on another OS, and actually try to program in that emulation of Notepad...)

Comment: @DidierL - We should have a popup that informs them that they're wrong and redirects them to the website to download any other IDE. It'll be done at random, because there are almost no IDEs worse than Eclipse.

Comment: I do not care where you write your programs @ArtOfWarfare. If you are asking "how to change notepad the font size?" that's not a programming question however you like to spin it, like "how to change the font size in word" isn't irrespectively you are writing a letter, a simple text file or tensorflow sourcecode.

Comment: @Braiam - I disagree with that. If you asked how to change the font size in IntelliJ, Sublime, or Eclipse, that would be considered on topic, because those are tools where you're writing your program. Similarly, asking about changing font size in Notepad is also valid, so long as the person is writing a program in it.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare well, it's on the help center, try disagreeing with that. I'm just telling you that what you "believe" is in contradiction with the help center.

Comment: @Joe: I'm pretty sure "purpose [doesn't] align with the goals of the user" is one of the best descriptions of a bad tool out there. This is especially true if you're suggesting that *trying to use Eclipse as an effective and efficient IDE* is not the purpose of Eclipse.

Comment: So, what do we do about the questions?

Comment: Except notepad isn't a *programming tool*. That's just not true any more than air is "programming air", and water "programming water." Because I use it, and I am a programmer does not make it a programming anything. See [my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349075/124486) for an argument against this form of categorization.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Except notepad can be used to write source code... In order to program, at a minimum you need the following tools: code editor, compiler, linker. Notepad can be used as a code editor and I think many of us have occasionally used it as such too. For example, what do you do if you find yourself with nothing but a Windows computer and you need to write or modify some source code.

Comment: I'm not saying that it is not a *tool*. It is a tool. If I found myself in a cave and and I needed to write source code, I'd have to invent a computer, an energy source, etc. You need all that to program too, yet that doesn't make them on-topic. Notepad isn't a *programming tool*. My intent to use it as such means nothing. It's a text-editor. Using it means I'm doing nothing more than editing text. The text can be on topic. But, the tool can't be. Neither can vim (shy of vim-script). They're text editors. Got a question on text-editors, take it to Super User.

Comment: Example type of question that might fit the bill is Notepad's inability to read cross-platform newlines for example. It will most definitely be a question with a massive duplicate history of course. I really wonder if in this day and age you can still ask a question about notepad which would not warrant closure of any kind...

Comment: You could never have asked a question about notepad that wouldn't warrant closure. It's a text editor that has nothing to do with programming if not for compiler-input being viewable in it. Tool: yes! Programming tool: nope! No more so than glass, or LED back-panels.

Answer (score -3):

As said on the help center all questions should be unique to software development context. That's why installing Windows isn't on topic (because it isn't unique), nor is installing programs in your system (on Windows click setup or equivalent; on Linux, package manager; MacOS whatever), changing fonts on your favorite text editor, etc. Those ain't tasks unique to software development, those are just task that you just happen to want to do while doing development. Also [boat programming](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14486/213575).

Answer (score -6):

We continue to use the standards that are currently in practice. There is a place for Notepad questions. If those questions don't fit the standard, they get flagged as such. Preventing a user from asking those questions, or being defensive because it doesn't fit our preconceptions, is not building a positive community. At that point, we become wikipedia fascists.

There's a guy named lonesome-something who does little more than berate question askers in the comments, yet his SO rep is through the roof. We don't need a system that rewards that kind of behavior.

The only stupid question is the one that goes unasked. The only stupid answer is the one that doesn't address the question. I've asked some pretty stupid questions and have received patient, well-constructed answers, regardless of the ambiguity of their placement.

That's a community that we need to foster.

Comment: *"The only stupid question is the one that goes unasked."* Uh, nope, pretty much half of the questions we get daily are quite stupid, e.g. "pls gimme teh codez!!1", "can I x with y if y doesn't let me x by design?", and "off-topic not about programming blah foo bar?"

Answer (score -9):

I agree with you. That's important to say. However, we're not in the majority here. I believe,

> Regardless of age, **ALL** questions about Notepad, or use of Notepad should be closed and migrated over to Super User.

There is question about delineating a site on

- *use and intent*, or
- *subject matter*.

A lot of people unfortunately fall into the *use and intent* camp. I don't understand them. Usually these people are somewhat pretentious and exclusionary. They will argue,

- A dd-wrt router used in a business application or marketed to businesses makes it on-topic on Server Fault, but if a home user does it — it's off topic.
- Amateur SQL-use is off-topic on Database Administrators.
- "Basic" questions don't belong on "this" site for experts.

The real reason why I'm on the *subject matter* camp, is because the site-delineation is only clean and useful to those that agree with us. Otherwise, for instance, VIM Questions are automatically on topic

- On Stack Overflow if you're programming with it.
- On Super User because you're just the end-user and it's only a desktop application.
- On VIM, because well vim.se is sane and defines itself on subject matter.
- On [GIS.se](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/148614/6052) if it's by someone in that industry.
- etc. etc.

If we delineate on subject-matter, vim-tag could prompt the user to voluntarily migrate to a better-matching site like vim.se. Or, we could even automatically migrate questions that were tagged `sql` or with just a specific variant of sql.

Just so you understand the crux of the argument, if Stack Overflow was defined as being *about* programming, rather than *for* programmers you'd be correct. But, it's not. Ideally things would be defined on subject-matter and questions would be placed in the most-specific site applicable.

### Update #1

- Web browsers: we should ban web-browsers too, unless you're using developers tools. Questions on web-browsers are as off-topic as questions on notepad. You want to read the docs on GCC using Firefox? It's still not on topic. Firefox isn't a programming tool.
- Operating systems aren't on topic: we have seperate sites for Unix, Apple, Ubuntu and SuperUser for Windows.
- APIs, including those that would interface with an operating system and its specific elements (registry, etc) - using them requires writing code and programming, that makes them on topic.
- "Shell scripts and batch files": require actually writing code (programming) are of course on topic.
- Excel as an end-user application, afaik, that has 0 to do with programming: off-optic.
- VBA is a language. It's use in Excel and outside is on topic. Using VBA, is programming. It's use in Excel has the same relation of vim-script to vim.

Comment: I think the general rule on SE is that sites define "on topic" based on *both* subject matter *and* intent. Vim would not be on-topic on GIS.se just because of *who asked the question*, but might be because of *what they were doing with it*. The opposite extreme is equally nonsensical: "how to write a novel using Vim" would obviously be off-topic on Stack Overflow, even though the "subject matter" was Vim, which can also be used to edit source code.

Comment: You're splitting a hair that needn't be split. Intent and who are the same category to me, and both are silly. In my world Vim questions wouldn't be fit for stack overflow because the subject matter isn't programming, unless you're writing c or vimscript. And even then, I'd say there is a site more catered to vimscript. I don't care what your intentions are or what you do for work.

Comment: I only mentioned the "who" because you said "if it's by someone in that industry", and you're the one who split the hair of "subject matter" vs "intent". A lot of your points are about sites other than SO, particularly SU vs SF, which I think is a whole different discussion. The fact is the "subject matter" of programming tools - version control, IDEs, debuggers, etc - has been defined as on topic for SO; and in order for that to make sense, we have to be able to close questions about using them for things that are not to do with programming.

Comment: @IMSoP right, and I believe myself and the op disagree that `"programming tools"` are defined by the intent of the user. Notepad is not a programming tool. You know that. It's a text editor. You use it to edit the text. The fact that the tool can be used to edit source code does not negate that.

Comment: The problem with these arguments is that if you don't say that it is not enough that "something is used for/when programming" to make it on-topic, but that it must be created for the purpose of programming, then where you draw the line. Okay so notepad.exe wasn't created as a programming tool. Neither did any of the web browsers so we should ban them too. This quickly turns very subjective. Is Excel with VBA a programming tool? Are operative systems on-topic? The Windows register? Shell scripts and batch files? Who dictates what's on topic and what is not?

Comment: @Lundin I've updated the answer to address all of your questions explicitly.

Comment: @EvanCarroll So your answer to my rhetorical question "Who dictates what's on topic and what is not?" is "I do"... great. You are kind of missing the point here.

Comment: It's not a dictation. I'm answer the question what is a "programming tool." If we don't have a criteria for exclusion everything is subjective. I'm stating that criteria should be in the tool, not in the intent or occupation of the user. If you're arguing I'm wrong, we can look up these tools and see what they're advertised to do. General purpose text editors, web browsers, and Excel are not programming tools.

Comment: Web browsers most definitely are development and even programming tools. They're pretty much invaluable when it comes to front-end development, providing the tools/means to do debugging and automated testing.

Comment: @EvanCarroll What you are missing is that the criteria for what counts as a programming tool is community consensus. Excel is not a programming tool, yet Excel formulas can be used as a very crude form of programming and such questions tend to be tolerated here. VBA which is definitely programming. HTML is not programming, yet considered on-topic. Web browsers are not programming tools yet all web programmers need to consider the various mainstream browsers. Operative systems are not programming tools, yet they need to be considered when programming.

Comment: I agree with the vast majority of that. *Considered when programming* is different though, isn't it? I consider all kinds of things when programming -- I don't think all of my considerations should be on topic because I am a programmer. I'm not doubting that consensus should play role, I'm doubting the majority's wisdom here and trying to direct them to a new method. The question should be is the tool a programming tool. Not is it a "consideration" or "does a programmer use it."

Comment: Perhaps not consensus, but domain knowledge. We can't go around and dictate what is on-topic in areas of application where we have no specific domain knowledge. I'm an embedded systems programmer - meaning it would be quite arrogant of me to start telling for example web programmers what tools that are on-topic for them to discuss. Because I lack the in-depth knowledge needed to realize what tools they need to use in their specialized branch. Similarly, because I do have domain knowledge about embedded systems, I would for example consider oscilloscopes to be programming tools.

Comment: I am a web developer. It's what I do. Web browsers are absolutely critical to what I do: I have to have them open all the time. They have absolutely nothing to do with **programming.** Everyone knows that. I'm a web developer, not an idiot. They're no more or less vital to my job than an operating system, or internet access -- the use of neither should be on topic here.