# Are blog-like Q&A pairs off-topic for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

**Note:** I usually avoid pointing to a specific user or question, as I don't want to do any public shamming, but I'm pretty sure that the specific question wouldn't be to hard to find anyway seeing as I'm going to describe it in depth. So I'll post it up front. And to further add to my point, the specific user encouraged me to open a discussion on meta, if I truly felt their question was off-topic (which I do).

---

**TL;DR: Are Q&A posts which are blog-like in structure off-topic for Stack Overflow?**

About a day ago, [J.F. Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4279/j-f-sebastian) posted [this question and answer pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43948164/how-to-add-support-for-int-literals-written-as-roman-numerals-to-cpython-what-d?noredirect=1#comment74948024_43948164) (**Note:** it is now deleted). The question is terse and direct. In it, Sebastian asked the question of how to extended the Python interpreter to be able to use roman numerals as built-in integer literals.

Now I'd like to bring up a point here about the question specifically:
If this was simply a regular question, I'm sure it would've been closed in short notice. **The question is asking for *us* to write the code to extend the Python interpreter**. essentially a "gimmeh teh codez" question. Very much off-topic.

However, the answer he gave is exactly what the question asked for, extensive and very lengthy. Describing in great detail how adding roman numeral support could be accomplished. And while I do think the Q&A is very interesting and helpful, I'm still pretty sure a Q&A pair like this is off-topic.

To add some context and be completly clear, here is the comment discussion between me and J.F. Sebastian that led to this question:

> This is really cool, thanks for sharing. However,there is nagging voice in the back of my mind telling me this is very much off-topic for Stackoverflow. – **Christian Dean**
>
> Sorry dude, but I'm going to have to go with my gut and vote to close this Q&A pair. However, I'd love to see this post on a blog somewhere (<sub>**Note: This is not my comment verbatim here as I deleted because of the next comment**</sub>). - **Christian Dean**
>
> @ChristianDean please, move your meta-comments to Meta. Read [the link from the /help/self-answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/05/22/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/) page. – **J.F. Sebastian**
>
> @J.F.Sebastian Seeing as couldn't find any post on meta about your question, I'm assuming you want me to remove my comment. I was simply letting you know why I was close voting. But I'll remove my comment. – **Christian Dean**
>
> @ChristianDean if you disagree with the content of the link then you could start Meta discussion that the policy should be changed and the link should be removed from /help/self-answer page. If you you are voting against the recommended behavior on the site despite being aware of the policy, it is your responsibility to change the policy (it is harmful for the site if votes do not reflect the policy). – **J.F. Sebastian**
>
> @J.F.Sebastian You seem to misunderstand me. I'm not voting against having Q&A's on the site. There are plenty of helpful Q&A's. I'm voting against the content of this specific Q&A. The is more of a blog post, and not a real question. But I think I'll take your offer up and start a meta discussion about this. – **Christian Dean**

As you may can see in the above discussion, Sebastian seemed adamant that his Q&A pair was on-topic for Stack Overflow, and gave a supporting link.

As I've said before, my gut feeling is that his Q&A post is off-topic. But seeing as he's been here longer and has more experience than me, I'd like to give him the benefit of the doubt and ask for the communities opinion. Also, there seems to have been Q&A pairs similar to this in the past. Such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-to-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely) post.

So to conclude, **are Q&A posts which are blog-like in structure off-topic for Stack Overflow?**

Comment: Self answered questions are certainly welcome, although imo the one in your example does read more like "I wrote this cool thing, here it is", in disguise, although on the other hand it's interesting, and programming related. and I think your specific example eludes a blanket general answer to your question, and you should probably either keep the scope to that specific question, or remove the specific example. One or the other. It usually makes more sense to deal with this kind of stuff case-by-case, since many cases are different.

Comment: @JasonC Yes, I know self answered questions are welcome here. And I _purposely_ avoided making this post specifically about _that_ post, because I didn't want it to seem like I was "calling someone out"(see my question's preamble). But if you think that my question is to broad, I'll consider narrowing its scope.

Comment: @Jason C: And it's not even a *useful* cool thing - it's right up there with the questions we used to get on April Fools each year.

Comment: (1) Don't remove the example, because it's an invaluable illustration. (2) Don't limit the scope to just that one example, because if a similar case comes along, of course this instance should serve as a template or precedent. (3) Closure of the question is not only completely justified, it doesn't even remove the question *or the answer* from the site! So nobody loses! Slam dunk. No brainer. Keep it closed.

Comment: @Glorfindel, gnat, Jan Doggen I don't see how my question is a duplicate. The duplicate linked is meant to address self-answered questions _in general_, and how to 'correctly' post them. _However_ - and this is important - my question is asking about a very _specific_ kind of self-answered question; blog-like self-answered questions. And I'm asking if they are on-topic, _not_ how one would go about posting such a self-answered question. Thus, I'm casting a vote to reopen this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Asking and answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

However, such questions must still be adhere to the site's rules about what constitutes a good question. A good way to "measure" that is imagining what would happen if this question would have been posted *without* the self-answer.

And in this case I think it's pretty safe to say that the question would have been closed as "too broad".

So I voted to close it as exactly that.

Comment: On the other hand, and playing devil's advocate here, it received a thorough answer, and it is also worthwhile to imagine what would happen if that answer was not posted by the OP, as it can be argued that [one's judgment of "too broad" may be changed if a proper answer is received](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223458/230261). The *purpose* of closing a question as "too broad" is to avoid wandering, unhelpful answers, but since a concrete, specific, complete answer was given, a "too broad" closure *may* not necessarily be serving a purpose any more.

Comment: @JasonC - I understand and respect the argument, but I don't agree with it. If that argument works for "too broad", then it should work for any of the close reasons. If someone asks a question on Stack Overflow that is not about programming, but gets an incredibly accurate, well-thought-out answer, does that make the question any more suitable for Stack Overflow? Absolutely not.

Comment: I really don't think it ever makes sense to judge a question by its answer or answers. How many very low-quality questions have we seen that have been thoroughly and accurately answered by good Samaritans or rep whores? Some people even advocate *downvoting the answerers* for encouraging such poor questions, no matter how good their answers are! Judging questions by their answers or judging answers by their questions are both highly misguided.

Comment: @JasonC lets play along for a while: I asked ["the ultimate question"](http://hitchhikers.wikia.com/wiki/Ultimate_Question) to which the only correct answer is 42. Does that automatically makes the question (which is well, the one that asks the meaning of life and everything else) on topic? Just where this stops? Is programming on a boat on topic?

Comment: @Braiam Well, the ultimate question isn't about programming, and the programming on a boat thing was a whole specific case that was deemed off-topic. It *is* case-by-case. Tbh, I don't know what to do about the specific example the OP gave, so I've refrained from taking any action, but it *is* about programming, it's just got a dubious style. But I understand exactly what you mean, and I don't have an answer for you. I think there's a fine line between proper questions, or twisting SO into being a personal programming blog. I really can't tell what side of that line *this* question is on.

Comment: @JasonC well, changing notepad fonts isn't about programming either, but [some claim that it's on topic so long as you are programming](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349071/is-notepad-on-topic/349104?noredirect=1#comment472743_349104), so that ship sailed. I prefer to mark the line where you need programming knowledge to answer the question, otherwise, it isn't programming.

Comment: That is not a bad point as such @JasonC, and I *do* frequently look at any answers before casting a close vote, but in this case the answer itself only verifies the "too broad" conclusion, as it's a long-winded tutorial and verifies that the question is too broad.

Comment: @JasonC Yes, you can by all means read through the answers and use them to inform your view on the scope of the question. That doesn't mean that just because someone posts an answer to the question that the question can't be Too Broad.  An answer that's clearly not providing a complete answer, an answer that's extremely lengthy and discussing various topics at length, an answer relying on lengthy external content as a part of the answer, etc. are all answers that clearly show that a question *is* too broad. But that the question has already attracted bad answers isn't a reason to not close it.

Comment: Why the question is "too broad" if it can be answered in a couple of short paragraph (the headers in my answer in a prose form)? (my question doesn't require a detailed answer, even a simple "use this `git grep` command, follow instructions in the commit messages" would suffice). I'm trying to understand the logic? Do you think closing such question makes the internet a better place? Do you think it encourages meaningful contributions on Stack Overflow?